# Getting feature ID by its name in sharePoint 2010 Powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell, feature

I want to get Feature ID by using its name in sharepoint 2010. I have activated the feature on my root site collection using web interface. What is the management shell command for doing this in sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you can filter the Get-SPFeature Powershell Cmdlet in order to get only those feature you know a part of the feature name.

This snippet will list all features, where "Content" is contained in the Display Name of a Feature :

```
Get-SPFeature | where { $_.DisplayName -like "*Content*" }
```

If you want to List a **sandboxed feature** by name try this:

```
Get-SPUserSolution -Site "<siteurl>" | ?{ $_.Name -like "*Content*" }
```

http://www.enterprisebugs.com/2011/11/find-sharepoint-feature-by-name.html

Answer (score 1):

Get-SPFeature | ? {$_.DisplayName -eq "YOUR_FEATURE_DISPLAYNAME"}

Answer (score 0):

Here are the examples to get the Details of a Feature.

If you are not sure of the name, use this snippet. It will get all with name contained in Display Name

```
Get-SPFeature -Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*YourFeatureName*"}
```

Get all feature installed in site scoped

```
Get-SPFeature -Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.Scope -eq "SITE"}
```

Get ID and name of each uniquely enabled feature on every SPWEB in site collection

```
Get-SPSite http://somesite | Get-SPWeb -Limit ALL | Where-Object { Get-SPFeature -Web $_ } | Select DisplayName,ID -Unique
```

Refered From: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607945.aspx